# Public Libraries / Private Library or other places to study in Lille

Tags: france, study, lille

I am a masters student in Lille. I am from a 3rd world country (Non -European) which is a very racist nation in the world.

I live in a CROUS room in Lille near Villeneuve-d'Ascq. I want to know of some safe spaces in Lille near Villeneuve-d'Ascq where I can study (Public Libararies/ Private Libraries/ other places which are peaceful for study).

*Note: I have not mentioned the race of dominant group or any other thing which could lead to any identification or anyone involved.*

Comment: Whilst I sympathise with your situation (and I know it can make one feel better to write complain and write out all their feelings),  I have edited your question to remove some details which are not necessary to answer your question.

Comment: @Xnero I understand. I am new to travel stackexchange. Thankyou very much for the edit.

Comment: Monsieur Google reveals [Yelp](https://www.yelp.com/search?cflt=libraries&find_loc=Villeneuve-d%27Ascq%2C+Nord) to advise you.

Comment: @DTPW Have you looked at the link above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are in a master’s degree, you are enrolled in a university (assuming you are enrolled at [Lille 1](https://www.univ-lille.fr/) but all public universities work exactly the same way)

All major universities have what we refer commonly as a BU (*bibliothèque universitaire*, university library), which is a very common place to study in French universities.

For [Lille University](https://www.univ-lille.fr/vie-des-campus/bibliotheques-et-learning-center), there are 4 of them (all information are in the link), all seems to be on-campus and all are accessible to you as you are a student of that university

And on the above link, there are also partnered and associated libraries to which you may have access with your student card *(I don't know if that's actually the case)*

Frequentation is highly variable, and it can definitely be crowded, but usually a very calm environment overall (this is from my experience at a different university, not Lille's in particular)